# How to skip GitHub workflow step if a file contains specific string?

Tags: node.js, git, github

I am trying to skip a workflow step if package name is scoped. Full repo [here](https://github.com/mayank1513/turborepo-template).

Here is what I am trying to achieve this

```
if: ! grep -q "@${{ github.event.repository.owner.id }}" package.json
```

However, GitHub throws error

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/publish.yml: (Line: 43, Col: 13, Idx: 1241) - (Line: 43, Col: 14, Idx: 1242): While parsing a tag, did not find expected tag URI.
```

How to fix this error or is there any other way to skip a step based on whether package name is already scoped?

Comment: I don't think this is a `git` question

Comment: Don't you think GitHub actions are related to git? Anyway, do you have any suggestion? Any idea I can try out

Comment: Are you merging? Committing? Creating branches? cherry-picking? rebasing? reverting? Creating worktrees? Diffing? Etc... the stuff that we use `git` (as a **vcs**, what the tag is about) for? Nope.... you are trying to do something that is not related to `git` (again, as a vcs).

Comment: Check https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/753

Answer (score 0):

thanks @eftshift0. I tried quoting with single quotes and the error disappeared.

However,

```
if: "! cat package.json | grep \"@${{ github.event.repository.owner.login }}\""
```

or

```
if: "! grep -q \"@${{ github.event.repository.owner.login }}\" package.json"
```

did not work.

Moving ahead with `continue-on-error` as `npm` doesn't allow double scoping.